# Access query across multiple tables with potentially non-existent related records

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm working on an MS Access 2010 database, and I have 5 tables I need to query.

Table 1 has an ID, name, a several other unrelated columns.
Tables 2 through 5 have their own IDs, the ID of the related record from Table 1, a date field, and then other miscellaneous fields.

I am trying to build a query to return the ID and name from table one, and the dates from tables 2-5.

I didn't really think that there would be any issues, but here I am. I have not done anything special with the query, just added the tables/columns to the Query Design view.

The query is working, sort of, however if the user has not created a related record with a matching ID in any of the related tables that record in table a is ignored.

I would like the query to return all records from table 1, and show me the dates from tables 2-5, even if one or all of them do not have a related entry.

I hope this makes sense... Any assistance is greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you are asking for.  Open the query in design view, double click on the line connecting table 1 to another table and select.  `All from table 1 and only those records...`

I think that should give you what you are looking for.  Otherwise you will probably need to post some more data about your other tables.

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy... I've been searching around for like a good hour. Thank you so very much @Newd!

Comment: @Matt No problem, if you want a good reference for SQL query Join types make sure you bookmark this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins Access doesn't tend to use the join terms in the visual query builder.  But if you look in SQL view you will see the join.